# Controlling a DC motor with a potentiometer

Tags: circuit-design, motor, dc-motor, potentiometer

I am trying to make a circuit with:

- [USB to open (5V)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YY555ZP)
- [5V DC motor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nmb-technologies-corporation/SE8G0NTMCA/6021452?utm_adgroup=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%20Shopping_Product_Low%20ROAS%20Categories&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_id=go_cmp-20243063506_adg-_ad-__dev-c_ext-_prd-6021452_sig-EAIaIQobChMIjeqSluGyggMVEPXICh0p-Q3lEAQYBCABEgIQ0vD_BwE&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjeqSluGyggMVEPXICh0p-Q3lEAQYBCABEgIQ0vD_BwE)
- [50 ohm potentiometer](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cts-electrocomponents/026TB32R500B1A1/203774?utm_adgroup=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%20Shopping_Product_Low%20ROAS%20Categories&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_id=go_cmp-20243063506_adg-_ad-__dev-c_ext-_prd-203774_sig-EAIaIQobChMIns-Rk8SyggMVgUZyCh3AuAdHEAQYASABEgIlF_D_BwE&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIns-Rk8SyggMVgUZyCh3AuAdHEAQYASABEgIlF_D_BwE)

I've forgotten a lot of the basics, and I just want to verify that this would work. I was going to connect the 5V power to the potentiometer, and connect the output from the potentiometer to the power of the DC motor, and ground everything with the USB ground.

The way I was thinking, the specs for the motor say that it has: 25mA no load current, 88mA load current, and 300mA starting current. The USB is rated at 5V with a 5A maximum current, but the motor would never draw 5A anyways.

The potentiometer has minimum resistance of 1 ohm, and maximum resistance of 50 ohm.

When we are looking at the 1 ohm case, we have

- No load: (25mA)*(1ohm)= .025V
- Load: (88mA)*(1ohm)=.088V
- Starting: (300mA)*(1ohm)=.3V

When we are looking at the 50 ohm case, we have

- No load: (25mA)*(50ohm)= 1.25V
- Load: (88mA)*(50ohm)= 4.4V
- Starting: (300mA)*(50ohm)= 15V <-issue

The 15V result doesn't make sense to me, and I am not sure how to fix it.

Edit: For all the calculations I did above, these voltages would be the voltage drop across the potentiometer, correct? Which means for the first calculation (no load: (25mA)*(1ohm)= .025V), the motor would receive 5V-.025V=4.975V.

Comment: You really should look at using a PWM Motor Control circuit for this.  Motor performance with varying loads will be absolutely awful if you try to control speed with a pot or rheostat.

Comment: @DwayneReid I was originally going to use a 555 timer in astable mode and a servo motor, but I honestly never understood the math behind it and I would really like to. I want to create this circuit for other to replicate, so I don't want to use a microcontroller. Also, I want the motor continuously running when the USB is plugged in, with the potentiometer varying the speed. I feel with the PWM, the values got weird when I tried to make a 100% (or as close to 100% as I could) duty cycle to keep it as a constant signal. I feel a constant wave is a better way to go

Comment: Yikes, wall of hyperlink text... consider using the Digikey "share" link which creates a short URL, or just inline the link in your text using the link syntax/button.

Answer (score 0):

The motor's own "resistance" varies as its speed changes. Consequently, when the motor is slowed by any mechanical load, its resistance falls, and since the 5V supply is shared between the potentiometer and the motor, the motor's  "share" drops, causing it to slow even more.

This is exactly the opposite of what you need. Ideally you'd like voltage across the motor to *increase* as load increases, or least remain constant. Your approach is very likely to fail.

This is why PWM is prevalent in such applications. PWM ensures that the *average* voltage across the motor remains constant, regardless of mechanical load. A 555 timer can be employed to do this.

As a compromise, and with caveats, this might work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1bMS1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistor will maintain a more-or-less fixed voltage across the motor, as set by VR1, in spite of changes in motor current demand, but it will not be able to supply more than 4.3V to the motor.

This configuration of transistor is called "emitter follower" or "[common collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector)". The name implies that emitter potential "follows" the base, whose potential is controlled by VR1, so that the position of VR1 still ultimately (but now indirectly) determines the voltage across the motor. The result is a much more "rigid" output voltage, albeit 0.7V lower in potential.

Comment: That's still wasting a lot of power in the pot. Would be better to use a larger one than 50 Ω.

Comment: @Hearth the 0.7V drop is bad enough. If the pot's much larger that "loss" will be worse due to base current, but I agree, perhaps 100Ω would be better.

Comment: @SimonFitch "when the motor is slowed by any mechanical load" what is the mechanical load you are referring to? sorry if this is a silly question. Does any of the math I did make sense? " Ideally you'd like voltage across the motor to increase as load increases, or least remain constant" But wouldn't this depend also on what we have to potentiometer set at? When the motor draws .088A, I thought that would mean it would receive 4.912V when the potentiometer is set to 1 Ohm, and .6V when the potentiometer is set to 50 Ohms.

Comment: I was looking into the 555 timer originally along with a servo motor, but I feel like I keep seeing different calculations for the resistor values being used, so I am not even sure how to make a prediction with it. Since I want the motor running continuously when the USB is plugged in (with the potentiometer being used to vary the speed), I thought I would use a 555 timer in astable mode to make a 100% duty cycle PWM signal to the PWM pin of the servo, with the potentiometer being connected to the power of the servo.

Comment: @jukebox41188 Your math might work for unchanging conditions, but it doesn't account for *changing* motor impedance, which changes with mechanical load. The mechanical load is anything acting to slow the motor shaft, like friction, or inertia, or a mass. Presumably your motor is turning something, and that's part of the "mechanical load"....

Comment: @jukebox41188 If you have set your potentiometer to 50Ω, the maximum current that could ever flow is \$\frac{5V}{50Ω}=0.1A\$. That's why your maths didn't work there, you simply cannot ever have 300mA when the supply is 5V and the pot is at 50Ω. If the pot is indeed at 50Ω, or even 25Ω, and you switch on power, I doubt that motor will even start to turn, because of static friction...

Comment: @jukebox41188 My answer is all about keeping voltage *constant* across the motor, even under load. If you use the potentiometer as a potential divider, as you intended to do, not only will the motor slow under slightly increasing mechanical load, it's likely to completely stall, because the voltage across it will drop very rapidly in this potential divider scenario, slowing it *even further*. The "emitter follower" circuit I showed you (mostly) prevents this voltage drop under mechanical load.

Comment: @SimonFitch If we set the potentiometer, would that mean the maximum current would be 5V/1 Ohm = 5A? The motor wouldn't draw 5A right, but the 300mA starting current would be allowed here right?

Comment: @jukebox41188 at 1Ω you'd probably see near the full 300mA flow, not 5A. That's because the motor's winding resistance is not 0!. Current will be determined by the *sum* of pot *and* motor winding resistance (they are in series). Motor resistance "appears" to increase as speed increases, and to decrease as speed decreases. I say "appears" because it's not just about the copper windings, it's also about magnetics, back EMF. This changing "apparent" resistance means that basic Ohm's law calculations are grossly inadequate, except for a stall/start condition.

Comment: @SimonFitch Okay, I guess I am having trouble reasoning how to do all of this without having accurate calculations. Why did you use a diode around the motor? Also, for the transistor, the way the 2N2222 transistor works is that it is a short circuit when it receives a voltage >.7V?

Comment: @SimonFitch I want the potentiometer to be able to vary the speed. If use the schematic you gave, that will always be the same speed right?

Comment: @jukebox41188 no, the speed will still be variable with the potentiometer. The transistor is there to "enforce" that voltage, even if the motor tries to change it (which it *will* try to do).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your intention is to use 5V USB (that is, Type A) then you're limited to 1A or 2A. 5A isn't an option. But, as it turns out, that's not relevant.

I looked further at this motor, and its coil resistance is approximately 15 ohms. This has an inherent current limit of 300mA at its lock-rotor torque, so no issue powering it with USB.

Other characteristics I came up with are:

- torque constant = 2.93 milli n-Nm/A (0.88 mN-m/300mA)
- back-emf constant (estimate) about 3.8 V-s/rad
- no-load friction (estimate) about 60 nano N-m-s/rad

This models a motor that spins ~12k RPM with no load drawing 25mA from 4.5V.

Now, consider that servo systems usually use motor current to control things, as this controls motor torque. Here's a circuit that can do that, with your motor roughly modeled based on the above parameters ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BOJyWoSAHA2BmBA2HMBAdgCYzIccAWcEkAVhBpyYFMBaMMAKBrDMa%20OgRYj6%20KFFiQIgmXDIIc8NeqqKqGLfAj5oCGlx0RIvAE7i6ZGpGshVdezDK8A5g6dfK082BJRKTB8ezAyU3DwcDUZMnJVDXU6AFkAewAXNKsAYQBXCwt2ADsMkBy00os0gBteACUQMWapCRcWe2Z2mEYPJuDQ-sk-XgB3B0odYRs7KF4AQxB4snAEFZxGFeIV9C6Y9RkiHDJGGgwcEjw7c8Yu6A3bsg216kh8EXf9%20DHVrZIpZbDcwAMxYx1%20Dm2ji20GYgh%20Gy2azBSJW5nGgMmS0YAMgOnMVihAWCyIozkcaj6ULJENs3R%20ITCEQh4XxPxOuJ0HOxUnMi0RPKW5EFu2kYA0ijANAQISwJDkGBxOBukrOCEYkGUOPwKhIerY4sp4wFdIms3RLBCFLo02tcysAu8Aik3jC3wxOMFmM9FpNwsdkGcliF60DjhwLrD9ko7vDkboAaDHoBnu5rvZnu8gPThORrJZ-2kGu%20ABNwMz84zy1zwAA5ARnXgXey2iS2sRmOaNVs2iTg9qzPYuWFN-EgABiEGYBiSSTAJl0cAg3AnFgAlgBjDJryoAHQAzhu0uxgcDN2uShleEA)):

[image]

This is a variable current control that has a range from 0 to 400mA. This may seem complicated but it really isn't. Here's how it works.

1. It uses a low-side sense resistor (200 mOhm) to measure the motor current, and compares that to a variable reference voltage to control the drive.
2. The sense voltage is amplified by 21x to scale it so that it can be used with a reference.
3. Amplified sense voltage is compared against a reference which varies from 0V to 1.69V. This gives a current range of 0 - 400mA.
4. The diode in series with the pot wiper ensures that when the pot is at minimum, the reference is actually zero.
5. I've used a FET here for the current driver. You can also consider a bipolar NPN.
6. The op-amp types I recommend are the [LMV324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv324.pdf), which will work fine on 5V.

Here's something a bit simpler ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BOJyWoSAHA2BmBA2HMBAdgCYzIccAWcEkAVhBpyYFMBaMMAKBrDMa%20OgRYj6%20KFFiQIgmXDIIc8NeqqKqGLfAj5oCGlx0RIvAE7i6ZGpGshVde2V4BzB08%20Vp5sCRs7EAobcklwcDUZJEYNDQgAWQB7ABckqwBhAFcLC3YAOxSQDKTCiySAG14AJWCgsHwXerIde3sg5jaZRnc6l1s%20wbbeAHcHSh1hQOGxnAw6YjIWHCXFqFHHRlWEJbmFnfWxgSlbdolT9YATYLC1rzXVgDkBGgxeHBIzugkpkDEzda1X4-CQrXwseydXzQHpFVjbJa-Nb2MzQQgkfCMYRyMixSAkJAyEiCFrkWgYjC0ViReyXdgAMwAhlkKileHCGoM9kMIpwYMSthgyTQKVS2DBiPgRJ8wJRGATKCoaSA6UyWWyPNzcVItWEZo55uADlqBuYrPdjVsjUtIXB3q0QAAxCDMAxxOJgEy6OAQbhOiwASwAxikA6UADoAZyDSQZ9ODAYKbKAA)):

[image]

Comment: The USB I am using has a maximum current of 5A, or at least that is what the link says. "And, another reason to use current: you need to limit the current to what your USB supply can handle" The motor won't use more than 300mA, so I don't see why this would be an issue? Where is the motor in the diagram above? And how did you choose those resistor values? Which resistor is the "low-side sense resistor"?

Comment: The link is for the cable. I'm talking about what USB can support. That's not 5A. It's normally 1A, or as much as 2A for some adapters. The motor could use more than 1A if for example the rotor locks up due to a mechanical block. In the sim the motor is the round thing; it spins slowly. To choose the resistors, I started with the sense resistor (0.2 ohm, '200m') and worked from there. 1A through 0.2 ohm x gain of 21 will be 4.2 V, about max for the pot, less one diode drop. You can modify the max current by changing the 20k resistor. 10k will give you 2A.

Comment: The data sheet doesn't give a DC resistance, or locked-rotor current. If the DC resistance is greater than 5 ohms, or locked-rotor current is less than 1 or 2A then there isn't a need for current limiting.

Answer (score 0):

A potentiometer is not a really good solution for motor speed control.  A potentiometer doesn't really control the motor speed.  It controls the power to the motor.  For a given load, that works out to speed control - but the load isn't usually constant.

The potentiometer you've chosen is also something of a specialty.  Sure, you can buy them from Digikey, but not everyone can do that.  Anyone trying to duplicate your circuit will have to order the same potentiometer (or a similar one that will also be a specialty part.)  People can't just rummage through the junk box for the needed parts or buy them from a local supplier.  Depending on the country, folks may not even be able to order from outside suppliers - import restrictions or just plain old postage costs may prevent it.

If you want other people to be able to easily duplicate your circuit, then you need to use commonly available parts.

A simple way to do that would be to use a common potentiometer with a transistor to handle the current.  Both are common parts, and there's no special requirements - your current and voltage are both low enough that nearly any common transistor can handle the job.

I went through a lot of this in a [review of motor speed controls](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/motorcontrol-toc) I made as part of developing a motor speed control for a really old sewing machine.

The simplest thing is to just replace your big potentiometer with a standard (low power) potentiometer and a transistor:

[image]

<sub>[Image source.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/motorcontrol1)</sub>

That circuit is a replacement for your circuit with the big potentiometer.  It is already an improvement, in that anyone can duplicate it using pretty much any potentiometer and pretty much any N-channel MOSFET.  N-MOSFET transistors are pretty common and cheap.  You can buy them on Amazon and pretty much any electronics supplier anywhere in the world (even little local markets) will have some.  The potentiometer is the same - I used a 2.2kohm part because I had one handy, but it could have been a 10k or 100k and still have worked just fine.

Other than that, it has all of the downsides of your original circuit:

1. It wastes power.
2. It regulates power, not speed.
3. It cannot maintain a given speed when the mechanical load changes.

If you rearrange those parts a little bit, you end up with a circuit that will try to maintain a set speed:

[image]

<sub>[Image source.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/motorcontrol2)</sub>

That circuit is a [source follower.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain)  It will try to maintain a constant voltage across the motor.  If the motor is stopped, it will automatically raise the current (reduce the resistance of the MOSFET) to make the motor turn.  You can set the motor voltage using the potentiometer.

This isn't a perfect circuit, but it is an improvement over the simple potentiometer circuit.

1. It still wastes power as heat.
2. It controls the speed of the motor rather than the power.
3. It will maintain a set speed, even if the mechanical load on the motor changes.
4. It still uses commonly available parts that anyone, pretty much anywhere, can get.

I used an [IRF540N](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/IRF540N.pdf) in those circuits, but pretty much any N-channel MOSFET with a low gate threshold voltage should work.

The source follower has the disadvantage that you can't get the full 5V to the motor.  There will always be a couple of volts dropped across it.  You won't be able to get the motor to run at full speed using the source follower circuit.

This circuit is a variant of the one [Simon Fitch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/688227/47070) gave.  Mine uses a MOSFET as a source follower while his uses a BJT as an [emitter follower.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_collector) Both set the motor voltage according to the potentiometer setting and adjust the current to make it work.

Regardless of what control method you use, the motor itself will have a certain minimum speed below which it will not turn reliably.

---

Most of the posts in that series of blog posts are more "thinking out loud" rather than really useful circuits.  Some of the experiments with PWM are just quick and dirty things that would result in a damaged Arduino if you ran them for more than a few minutes.  The final circuit with PWM control of a universal motor running from 230VAC mains is working (I've been using it to sew leather  the last few days,) but I haven't yet posted the final designs and software on github.

Comment: thanks so much! This makes sense I think, I'll have to look more into N channel MOSFETS. How would those potentiometer values work if its only getting 5V. I read other posts where people chose potentiometer values like the ones you chose, and the motor was barely able to move due to so much resistance.

Comment: It's more in the choice of the MOSFET than in the potentiometer value.  You need a MOSFET with a low gate threshold.  The voltage from the potentiometer is the same - the gate of a MOSFET doesn't draw current like the base of a BJT.  It might take longer for the MOSFET to react to a larger potentiometer, but I don't think you'll notice the difference.

Comment: @jukebox41188: There's a couple of short videos in the blog post the second picture came from.  The second video shows the source follower.

Comment: from the IRF540N datasheet, it says the gate threshold voltage has a minimum of 2V and a maximum of 4V, so that means when the gate (which would be what is output from the potentiometer) is in that range, the gate is shut and the motor receives the voltage after the voltage drop across the potentiometer. And when the gate voltage isn't in that range, it receives the straight 5V from the power source (the 5V USB I want to use)

Comment: How is the voltage from the potentiometer the same if you can vary the resistance?

Comment: The threshold voltage minimum is somewhere around 2 to 4 volts.  You are allowed up to 20V between the gate and the source.  The source follower "looks" at the gate voltage (adjustable through the potentiometer) and adjusts the current from the drain to the source in order to raise the source voltage to match the gate voltage.  No current flows from gate to source.

Comment: When the gate is more than 2 volts above the source, current will flow through the drain to the source.

Comment: When the gate is less than 2V above the source, no current flows through the MOSFET - the motor stops.  When the gate is more than 2V above the source, the MOSFET will conduct current to maintain the voltage at the source at about 2V below the gate voltage.  From 2V to 20V, the source voltage will follow the gate voltage by allowing as much current through as it takes to keep the motor voltage at 2V below the gate voltage.

Comment: Sorry, I think I am getting confused. The potentiometer will always have a 5V drop across it when plugged in to the 5V source, right? And if we were to use a 2.5k Ohm potentiometer (the one I found online has a minimum resistance of 500 Ohms), wouldn't that mean the maximum current across the potentiometer is .01A (5V/500 Ohms)? And so the source would try to have 3V (2V drop) and reach a current to make that voltage?

Comment: There are three pins on a potentiometer.  One is at 5V, one is at 0V, and the third one varies as you turn the knob.  Current goes **through** not across.

Comment: Get out a voltmeter and a potentiometer.  Connect the outer pins to +5V and ground. Connect the voltmeter from ground (black probe) to the middle pin of the potentiometer (red probe.) Turn the potentiometer.  See how the voltage varies.

Comment: I guess I am just trying to figure out when we would see that 2V as the gate voltage. It seems hard to predict when I can't calculate it out. If I used a rated 5V motor with 250mA load current, and I have the potentiometer set to the minimum of 500 Ohms, do you know how I could predict if this would work?

Comment: A potentiometer is a voltage divider.  Take the 2.2k potentiometer I used.  Set it so that there's 500 ohms between the wiper and the 0V.  There will be 5V/2200 ohms = 2.3 milliamperes flowing through the potentiometer. 500 ohm * 2.3milliamperes = 1.1V on the wiper.

Comment: With the potentiometer set to the middle of its range, you will get about 2V on the gate of the MOSFET.  You could put a series resistor in series between ground and the ground pin of the potentiometer of about half the value of the potentiometer.  Say, 1k for the 2.2k potentiometer.  That will put the lowest voltage from the wiper at about 2V.

Comment: Oh okay I see. So if we set the wipe of the potentiometer to 2V/ .0023A = 869.5 Ohms , the MOSFET would see 2V at the gate voltage, and the motor still wouldn't move because it would be trying to meeting 2V-2V=0 voltage. If we set the wiper to 1000 Ohms, the gate voltage would be 2.3V, and the MOSFET would adjust the current to meet 2.3V-2V = .3V ? But when we set the wiper to the maximum (The maximum of the 2.5kOhm one I saw is 1 M Ohm), that would be a huge voltage drop (2300V on the wiper), but this exceeds the gate threshold, so the MOSFET wouldn't change?

Comment: I don't know where you got 1M ohm.  The maximum value of a 2.2k potentiometer is 2.2k.  The wiper picks up a voltage somewhere between the maximum and minimum voltage.

Comment: https://www.ttelectronics.com/TTElectronics/media/ProductFiles/Datasheet/P160.pdf I can't seem to find a potentiometer that doesn't have a huge maximum value

Comment: The "resistance range 500-1M" is for the product line.  The manufacturer makes various models, each with a different resistance.  There are models with 500 ohms.  There are models with 1M.  There are models with 2.2k.

Comment: So for this 2.5k Ohm potentiometer, We have the following scenarios: Minimum: 5V/2.5k Ohms = 2mA, 500 Ohm*2mA= 1V -> the MOSFET won't change since this is below 2V. Maximum: 5V/2.5k Ohms = 2mA, and then the whole 5V would be Vout, the MOSFET would see 5V and work to change its current to meet 3V? Should I worry about protecting the MOSFET since the motor won't change the current instantly and may have a big voltage drop?

Comment: May I make a suggestion?  Get a potentiometer, an IRF540 MOSFET, a motor, and a 5V supply.  Try it out.  Nothing bad can happen.  With the voltages and currents involved, nothing will be able to burn out or over heat.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help!